# Application systemctl not executing entire row of ExecStart from file httpd.service

Tags: systemd, apache-httpd, systemctl

The exact file location is:

`/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/httpd.service`

I modified the ExecStart line to reflect the following:
`ExecStart=echo START && echo test > /root/out.txt && echo $OPTIONS > /root/out.txt && echo END && /usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND`

As you can see I used && to separate commands.  I am trying to find ways to help debug outputs on services.

After I made this change, the system was still starting apache when I executed the  "`systemctl start httpd.service`" command.  However, it gave an error stating the startup file had been modified (which is fine) however it looks like it pulled the actual startup line from another unknown location as the file /root/out.txt was never even created. If anyone could give me more info on why this behavior occured I would be very grateful.

In the past before the new systemd/systemctl, I would use the following command to watch what the startup scripts were doing in a similar situation:

`bash -X /etc/init.d/httpd start`

As you can see with systemctl, this is not an option.  Please keep in mind that I want to do similar mechanisms on other services, not just apache and this is just an example.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have access to the system in question anymore.  It appears that I had failed to run the "systemctl daemon-reload" command.  I saw info on this in the erros but I had figured this command rebuilds the file I was modifying.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After modifying systemd service file you need to execute following command in order to reload systemd configuration:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

This will probably solve problem you have with your changes not being executed. But this will not solve your primary problem: adding more actions during service start. Right now you are trying to extend existing command using `&&`, but according to [systemd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=):

> If more than one command is specified, the commands are invoked sequentially in the order they appear in the unit file. If one of the commands fails (and is not prefixed with "-"), other lines are not executed, and the unit is considered failed.

You can also use `ExecStartPre=` and `ExecStartPost=` lines.

Comment: Great to know it's got other and better ways to do this.  If I did want to place all of these commands on the same `ExecStart=` line, which delimiter should I use (rather than &&)?

Still trying to figure out how this loads configs (such as how it populates the $OPTIONS variable).

Comment: Why would you want to do everything in one line? In my opinion it's better to create separate line for each command. Anyway [systemd.service doc](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines) has entire section about command lines